# How to start a Scala akka actor

Tags: scala, akka

Below class is causing an error at line new HelloWorld :

```
Exception in thread "main" akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: You cannot create an instance of [HelloWorld] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the documentation.
  at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:219)
  at akka.actor.Actor$class.$init$(Actor.scala:436)
  at HelloWorld.<init>(HelloWorld.scala:4)
  at Driver$.main(HelloWorld.scala:38)
  at Driver.main(HelloWorld.scala)
```

So I try  :  `val hw = actorOf(new HelloWorld)`
But this causes a compiler error :

```
not found: value actorOf
```

How should HelloWorld below be implemented ?

Reading other Scala docs an act method is requried to be defined within the class that extends Actor and then invoke the start method on this class, is there a reason for using actorOf instead of defining an act method ?

Below class is taken from Scala akka docs http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala.html :

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Actor._
import akka.actor.Props

class HelloWorld extends Actor {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    // create the greeter actor
    val greeter = context.actorOf(Props[Greeter], "greeter")
    // tell it to perform the greeting
    greeter ! Greeter.Greet
  }
  def receive = {
    // when the greeter is done, stop this actor and with it the application
    case Greeter.Done => context.stop(self)
  }

  object Greeter {   

    case object Greet
    case object Done


  }
  class Greeter extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case Greeter.Greet =>
        println("Hello World!")
        sender ! Greeter.Done
    }
  }


}

object Driver {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      new HelloWorld
    }

}
```

Comment: act() and start() belong to the old and deprecated Scala actors, Akka is a different actor implementation, please refer to the docs at http://akka.io.

Comment: @RolandKuhn thanks for link, after some digging this doc is proving useful : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#actors-scala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to edit your main as shown below. Secondly, in line-5, you need to change it to `context.actorOf(Props(new Greeter))`. This is because your `Greeter` does not have `apply` function defined, hence you need to manually create Greeter object yourself.

Working code below:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

class HelloWorld extends Actor {

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    // create the greeter actor
    val greeter = context.actorOf(Props(new Greeter), "greeter")//line 5
    // tell it to perform the greeting
    greeter ! Greeter.Greet
  }
  def receive = {
    // when the greeter is done, stop this actor and with it the application
    case Greeter.Done => context.stop(self)
  }

  object Greeter {   

    case object Greet
    case object Done


  }
  class Greeter extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case Greeter.Greet =>
        println("Hello World!")
        sender ! Greeter.Done
    }
  }


}

object Driver {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val system = ActorSystem("Main")
      val ac = system.actorOf(Props[HelloWorld])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use your main class do the following:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
object Driver extends App {    
    val system = ActorSystem("System")
    val hw = system.actorOf(Props[HelloWorld], name = "hw")
}
```

Which will create a new actor system and then create the HelloWorld actor using that actor system.

You can also follow the akka instructions: 
set Akka.Main as the main class and give the program "com.example.HelloWorld" as argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
val greeter = context.actorOf(Props(new Greeter), "greeter")//line 5
```

I don't think you need to have a new keyword there for Greeter. I believe the Props does that for you already. If anything having a new should be a